# mongoDb c++ driver ignores mongoclient library

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, linker-errors

I try to port my game code to Unix platform from windows 7. I'm using compiled from source latest c++ mongodb driver. Same steps as on windows. But i met some troubles with mongoclient library linking. I have branch of errors here [Many many errors](http://pastebin.com/J42yes5u). When i dont link libmongoclient.a at all g++ generates same errors. I have g++ 4.4.5 version. What i missed here?

Update: 
I'm trying to compile with mongo_client_lib.cpp Result will announce later. After recompiling boost and mongo still same errors. When i include mongo_client_lib.cpp i have [More errors](http://pastebin.com/zwtzMaGE). It still doesn't see library file for mongo client. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally reason was in wrong compilation mode. MongoDb provides driver for release builds. I was built in debug mode. Building in release x64 made mongoclient work!

Answer (score 0):

The example in [the MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21266598#C%2B%2BDriverCompilingandLinking-Linux) shows `-lmongoclient` listed *before* the `-boost...` libs.  Yours has it after.

Comment: Changing the order didnt help =(

Comment: I assume `/usr/include/mongo_src/mongodb-mongo-80ff8f7/build/linux2/normal/client_build` does definitely contain the compiled 64-bit mongoclient lib file?